# how can I set an empty mvn property in m2eclipse?

Tags: m2eclipse, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to make a mvn run-configuration in eclipse/m2eclipse. I want to mimic the following mvn command:

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
```

However, when I add a parameter to the configuration, I must provide a value for the key "maven.surefire.debug".

Any workarounds ?

Comment: setting the property to true does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bashing myself:

"Empty property" does not make sense.

If we leave out the value of a property, the default value of that property will be used, which is true in this case.